# Applying "get" to all elements in a vector -or- Working with sequential variables in r

Tags: r

I have half a dozen matrices: m1, m2, m3, m4, m5, and m6.  For the sake of a simple example, let's say they look like this:

```
m1<- matrix(1:10, 2, 5)
m2<- matrix(11:20, 2, 5)
m3<- matrix(21:30, 2, 5)
m4<- matrix(31:40, 2, 5)
m5<- matrix(41:50, 2, 5)
m6<- matrix(51:60, 2, 5)
```

Ultimately, I want to apply a function to all 6:

```
f(m1,m2,m3,m4,m5,m6)
```

Because the number of matrices will vary every time I run the scrip, I'm looking for a way to do this programatically.  My first through was to take the function of:

```
paste("m",1:6,sep="")
```

The expression above returned a string:

```
[1] "m1" "m2" "m3" "m4" "m5" "m6"
```

To find the values, rather than the names of the matrices, I tried adding "get" into the mix, by taking the function of:

```
get(paste("m",1:6,sep=""))
```

But the "get" expression only returned values for the m1 and ignored everything else that I wanted.  So, I began messing around with for loops:

```
for(k in 1:6){
if(k == 1){b<- paste("m",k,sep="")}
else{b<- c(b, paste("m",k,sep=""))}
}

> b
[1] "m1" "m2" "m3" "m4" "m5" "m6"
```

This is the same string that I got from my first attempt.  Consequently, the following expression failed:

```
w<- f(b)
```

I also tried:

```
w<- f(get(b))
```

Somewhat predictably, R recognized m1 as a matrix, but ignored the rest of the terms in B.

I also tried:

```
w<- f(get(b[1:6]))
```

When I did this, I get the same result as above.

Finally, I also tried turning b into a list:

```
b<- list(m1,m2,m3,m4,m5,m6)
```

I had hoped to use lapply(b, g), but the function (which I didn't write and am obligated to use) doesn't work correctly when placed into lapply.

Any other thoughts on how I can accomplish this seemingly simple task?  I'm still relatively new to R, so there may well be a well-known approach of which I'm ignorant, but I could find nothing in my search of existing documentation, and I feel foolish for needing help to sort-out something this small.  Cheers to the forum for its help.

Comment: Try `sapply(ls(pattern = "m"), get)`.

Comment: It's hard to be too specific, but I agree with one of the answers below: the real problem here is that you're doing things in a sort of un-R-like way. The best solution is probably to change your function `f` such that it accepts a single list of matrices, rather than a long list of arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be going about this the wrong way. Put your matrices into a list, and then `lapply` your function `f` to all elements of the `list`.

```
m1<- matrix(1:10, 2, 5)
m2<- matrix(11:20, 2, 5)
m3<- matrix(21:30, 2, 5)
m4<- matrix(31:40, 2, 5)
m5<- matrix(41:50, 2, 5)
m6<- matrix(51:60, 2, 5)

f<-function(x) sum(x) # A test function
l<-list(m1,m2,m3,m4,m5,m6)
lapply(l,f)
```

You might say that is fine, but what happens when I have thousands of matrices? How do I create that list? Most of the time you can generate your `matrices`, or read them into a list from the beginning. Here is how you would generate them as a list:

```
start<-seq(1,51,by=10)
gen<-function(x) matrix(x:(x+9),2,5)
l<-lapply(start,gen)
```

Usually, if you start thinking about iterating over names of variables, you're doing it wrong. That is true in most programming languages, from my experience.

Answer (score 2):

Store your matrices in a list `l = list(m1,m2,m3,m4,m5,m6)`, and use `do.call(f, l)`.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
m1 <- matrix(1:4, ncol=2) # some dummy matrices
m2 <- m1*2
m3 <- m2+2
m4 <- m1*3


b <- paste0('m', 1:4)
b

for(i in 1:length(b)) {
 print( get(b[i]) )
  }
```

Or using `lapply`

```
lapply(b, get)
```